# How Do I Take a Variable No of inputs in python?

Tags: python

For example

```
print("Which Of the Following Activities Do you Enjoy?")
print("1)Swimming\n2)Jogging\n3)Basketball\4)Football\n5)Yoga")
```

I would like the user to input their choices like 1,2 or 3,4,5 etc. i.e get variable no of inputs from the user.

Comment: Does this question actually looks like you had in mind? If not, please read [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) (You may also be interested in reading [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is, you can get the input from the user as a string and use `split(',')` to get the array of all the user's choices.

```
str = input('')
str = str.split(',')
for choice in str:
    if choice == "1":
        print("Swimming")
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Pythons [raw_input()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) returns a string, but you can split this string to get a list, using the `raw_input().split()`

So in your case you can do the following.

```
print("Which Of the Following Activities Do you Enjoy?")
print("1)Swimming\n"
      "2)Jogging\n"
      "3)Basketball\n"
      "4)Football\n"
      "5)Yoga")

user_choice = raw_input().split(' ,')
```

and then you can iterate through `user_choice` and get the individual choices.

```
for choice in user_choice:
    # do what you want
```

Comment: You should split on spaces as well, to be more user friendly. str.split can take multiple separator characters, like this: `raw_input().split(' ,')`